# How to download "tikz" package for texlive in Windows 10? (can't find it on the texlive manager)

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive, windows

I want to download the **tikz** package for a beamer presentation in order to create a pop-up effect.

Although i searched for the package in the **texlive manager**, i can't find any package with exactly the name "tikz". I found tikz-inet, tikz-ladder and others but no tikz.

Help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I guess it's the same as  for MiKTeX: install `pgf`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package is called pgf :

> pgf – Create PostScript and PDF graphics in TEX PGF is a macro
>   pack­age for cre­at­ing graph­ics. It is plat­form- and
>   for­mat-in­de­pen­dent and works to­gether with the most im­por­tant
>   TEX back­end drivers, in­clud­ing pdfTEX and dvips. It comes with a
>   user-friendly syn­tax layer called TikZ.
>
> Its us­age is sim­i­lar to pstricks and the stan­dard pic­ture
>   en­vi­ron­ment. PGF works with plain (pdf-)TEX, (pdf-)LATEX, and
>   ConTEXt. Un­like pstricks, it can pro­duce ei­ther PostScript or PDF
>   out­put.

https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: @stevi Good to hear that the answer helped you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.